# NoSuchElementException Scanner java

Tags: java

I'm getting the below exception in my java project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.ooad.ooadfirstassignment.Employee.readData(Employee.java:25)
    at com.ooad.ooadfirstassignment.Salaried.readData(Salaried.java:16)
    at com.ooad.ooadfirstassignment.Factory.<init>(Factory.java:21)
    at com.ooad.ooadfirstassignment.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:25)
```

The Code is as follows :

=====================================================

```
public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream empTextStreamIn = null;
        try
        {
            empTextStreamIn = new FileInputStream("Employee.txt");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fex)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee File not found");
            fex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Factory f = new Factory(empTextStreamIn);
        empTextStreamIn.close();

    }

}
```

====================================================================

```
public class Factory 
{
    public Factory(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        int empType;
        String EmpID = null,DeptID = null;
        double salary=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(empTextStreamIn);
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            empType = sc.nextInt();
            switch (empType) 
            {
                case 1:Salaried salr = new Salaried(empTextStreamIn);
                        salr.readData();

                                      System.out.println("EmpType="+empType+"   EmpID="+EmpID+"   DeptID="+DeptID+"   Salary="+salary);
```

The code goes on so this is the main part though.

## Next the Employee Class

```
public class Employee 
{
    String EmpID, DeptID;   //Unique detail for Employee class

    protected Scanner sc;

    Employee()
    {

    }
    public Employee(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        sc = new Scanner(empTextStreamIn);

    }
    void readData()
    {
        String EmpID = sc.next();
        String DeptID = sc.next();
    }
```

## }

Salaried Class

```
public class Salaried extends Employee
{
    double salary;  //Unique detail for Salaried class

    public Salaried(FileInputStream empTextStreamIn) 
    {
        super(empTextStreamIn);

    }
    void readData()
    {
        super.readData();
        salary = sc.nextDouble();


    }

}
```

Kindly help me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote ?

Comment: Does hasNextLine() return true even if the following line is empty? Have you tried to end the file not with a newline? (i.e. no newline at the end of the last line)

Comment: changed the the readDate Function in the Employee class as "while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
 empType = sc.nextInt();
 EmpID = sc.next();
 DeptID = sc.next();
}" and the salaried readData() function as "super.readData();
while(sc.hasNext())
salary = sc.nextDouble();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Scanner` class uses an internal buffer. You create a `Scanner` object in the `Factory` class. This `Scanner` reads from the underlying `FileInputStream` into its own buffer. I suspect your input file is so small that the whole file fits into this buffer. That means that the `Scanner` in the `Factory` will read through the whole `FileInputStream`. After this, you create a new Scanner object in the `Employee` class, using the same `FileInputStream`. However, the first `Scanner` has already consumed all the content in that `FileInputStream`. Hence, because there is no data, that `Scanner` throws an exception.

So what you need is probably just to ensure that you use the same `Scanner` object when reading from the file, instead of instantiating several different scanners on the same `FileInputStream`.

<EDIT>

To verify that this is the case, you can try inserting the following line inside the while loop in the `Factory` class:

```
System.out.println("Data could be read from the InputFileStream: " 
                    + (empTextStreamIn.read() != -1));
```

(Note that the read method can throw an IOException, so you will have to surround it with a try-catch block)

</EDIT>

Comment: @ Alderath As you had guessed Data could be read from the InputFileStream: false many times

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your test file contains less data than what you're trying to read, because that's why [this exception is thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29). It's always better to check if the input has any next element using [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) method.

Comment: I have used hasNextLine() in my Factory class. But still the error remains.

Comment: Use it each time before the next

Comment: used it but it is displaying values as null

Comment: All the four fields. I guess I'm going wrong somewhere in passing the filestreams

Comment: Basically passing the text file in the MainClass where there are 4 fields in each line(Emp Type, Emp ID, Dept ID and salary. I want the main Employee class to pull the first three and Salaried(which extends employee)  class to pull salary data from file.